# Method not accepting the data type that it was written to accept

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I've been given a method header pre-written:
`public static boolean checkingArray (int[] data)` 
I then have to write the method to check an array for if its sorted in numerical order, and all that went fine.
But when I try calling the method on the example arrays I've been given, it gives me this error:

`Cannot invoke checkingArray() on the array type int[]`

This is the code that I've written, can anyone explain if I did something wrong or if my code is bugged, or what's happening? I'm totally lost on any kind of solution.

```
public static boolean checkingArray (int[] data) {
        boolean isSorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i <data.length;) 
            if (data[i] >= data[i+1]) 
                isSorted = false;
        return isSorted;
    }
    
    static int example1[] = {1, 6, 9, 4, 5, 10, 2, 7};
    static int example2[] = {3, 8, 9, 12, 20};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Array 1 is sorted: " + example1.checkingArray());
        System.out.println("Array 2 is sorted: " + example2.checkingArray());
        }
    }
```

Comment: example1 is an array...arrays don't have a checkingArray() method, thats why

Comment: checkingArray(example1)

Answer (score 0):

`checkingArray` is not a method of `int[]`

It is a static method of your class, which takes an argument of type `int[]`.

Call it like

```
System.out.println("Array 1 is sorted: " + checkingArray(example1));
```